# How to get information about an SQL Select statement

Tags: sql

I am wondering if it is possible to get the real name of the tables/fields from which each field in a select statement comes from.

Lets say you have two tables, Creditors and Debtors both have the fields Code, Name and Phone.

If a user enters the following sql statement:

```
SELECT Code AS CustomerCode, Name AS CustomerName, Phone AS ContactNumber FROM Debtors.
```

This will result in SQL server returning field names CustomerCode, CustomerName and ContactNumber.

Is it possible to get from the SQL server some sort of meta data that maps each field to its real name and the table it comes from?

Programmically, given an SQL select statement, I want to be able to determine the real name of each field and the real name of the tables they come from.

I don't want to parse the SQL myself so I thought that there might be away to send the statement to the sql server and get back this information without the row data.

What we are trying to do is implement table/field level security. A user can enter an sql statement to select fields from a table or across multiple tables (using joins) and have the results displayed in a table.  The fields get added dynamically to a grid control but only the ones that the user is allowed to see.

If the user joins multiple tables how do we know programmically which fields come from which table? the problem gets worse if they use aliases in the SQL.

Currently this is working on a legacy in house built sql engine (that uses a proprietary database) which can return all of the required table/field information without the row data so part of the applications security model is built around this.  However moving this application to something like SQL server might prove difficult if we can't get this to work.

Besides Sql server, do any other sql databases support this type of functionality?

Comment: This is tricky to do in a general way because result set columns don't always map directly back to table columns.  (in fact, they frequently don't).  You could have a result column that's the sum of values in rows in table A and table B.  Or, you could have a table who's data is used for a join that's not shown in the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot get that information.

You can probably handle your problem in many databases, however, by using GRANT / REVOKE security in the database itself.  Assuming that users are logging into the database itself (not just your application), many DBMSes allow you to GRANT SELECT privileges on restricted columns from a table.  Using that technique, it will not fool the server if the user specifies ALIASes for columns.

A quick google indicates that at least PostgreSQL, SQL Server, and Oracle offer column level GRANT SELECT protection based on userid.

Interesting question, by the way.

Comment: +1. Good answer, but I would personally try to avoid granting column permissions in all but the simplest cases.

Comment: Me too, but presumably the OP really does need to do this and apparently already _is_ doing it in the application code.  If he can move it to the database layer, I can't imagine it will be any _harder_ to maintain (he can repurpose the existing management front end to use GRANT and REVOKE).  If he _really_ needs to do it, most databases will already handle it.

Comment: Using grant/revoke sounds like that way we need to go, thanks for that.  One more problem is that a user can write a query and then drill down on the results returned.  For example, a user writes a query to select invoices from the invoice table (invoice number, invoice date, customer name, total gross, total tax).  If you user then double clicks on the row the application looks at the first column and figures out that this column came from the invoice table.

Comment: Based on the table and field name it knows to launch the invoice details screen passing it the invoice number which will in turn display the transactions that make up the invoice. If a user has used aliases and if we can't get the real table/field involved in the select then I don't see how this could work on sql server. Any suggestions?

Comment: After a bit of googling I found this on microsofts site SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable. The GetSchemaTable method returns a dataset containing the resultset meta data for a select statement. This includes the name of the column as returned in the result set, the real name of the column and store in the table and the real name of the table. This seems to be supported by sql server, I wonder if other database support it.

Comment: The Enterprise class SQL servers have had row level and column level security for many years, downstream it is new (MS 2008, still figuring outhow to do it). Extensions to the SQL standard security model.  Absolutely no performance impact. They also handle column level encryption, but that costs a little.

Comment: @no spoon.  All that is handled by SQL.  The problem is, you have been doing that in app code, which is the wrong place to implement security.  If you stop doing that, and do normal GRANT/REVOKE per table per LOGIN, the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

No. The whole point is you should only know the name presented to you and not where it came from.

The way to solve your problem is to remove all access from tables and only grant access through views with appropriate access permissions.

Comment: That doesn't strike me as having the granularity that the OP is requesting.

Comment: column permissions are indeed possible in MS SQL 2k8; but managing them can be, lets say, interesting.

Comment: also note: A table-level DENY does not take precedence over a column-level GRANT. This inconsistency in the permissions hierarchy has been preserved for backward compatibility. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx

Comment: Presumably, they're already dealing with the issue of handling permissions on the column level already, just with the added complexity of doing it themselves.  But I agree, _any_ column level permission management will be time consuming and, probably, error prone.

Comment: "Backward compatibilty" (not your post, but the MS statement) is bulldust.  Sybase and DB2 implemented it years ago, on top of the SQL Standard security model, with no issues whatsoever. The simple truth is 2008 is a new codeline, land it has many bugs that 2005 did not have; like when 2005 was new and had many bugs that 2000/6.5 did not have.  New codelines are hilarious, but MS types buy it.  In the Sybase DB2 Enterprise market, we never throw out precious code, we just keep adding to it, because the structure allows it.